# Add auto-incrementing column in temporary Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add an auto-incrementing column to a table using a Common Table Expression.

Suppose we have a table `TEMP` with one column `COL` as follow:

TABLE TEMP

```
+---+
|COL|
+---+
|a  |
+---+
|b  |
+---+
|c  |
+---+
|d  |
+---+
|e  |
+---+
|f  |
+---+
|g  |
+---+
|h  |
+---+
```

Is it possible to add an auto-incrementing column to the temporary table and to have the following result?

Table CTE

```
+---+--+
|COL|ID|
+---+--+
|a  |1 |
+---+--+
|b  |2 |
+---+--+
|c  |3 |
+---+--+
|d  |4 |
+---+--+
|e  |5 |
+---+--+
|f  |6 |
+---+--+
|g  |7 |
+---+--+
|h  |8 |
+---+--+
```

Is It possible to make that using CTE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need an analytic query, for instance [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), which returns the sequence of a row, within a partition (not required), and in the order specified.

```
select col, row_number() over ( order by col ) as id
  from temp
```

Comment: No problem @dancko, welcome to Stack Overflow :-). Take a look at the other windowing functions as they can be extremely useful. Also, if you haven't already have a look at the [about] page to gain an idea of how to get on here. It'll help in the long run as we're sometimes a little different to the rest of the internet :-).